# '1 required argument(s) expected but 0 found' error flutter

Tags: flutter

**main.dart.**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:finalproject/screens/chat_screen.dart';

import 'package:finalproject/widgets/auth_form.dart';


Future<void> main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(

      title: 'flutter chat',

      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.red,

        backgroundColor: Colors.red,

        accentColor: Colors.green,

        accentColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,

        buttonTheme: ButtonTheme.of(context).copyWith(

          buttonColor: Colors.red,

          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,

          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(

            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),

          ),
        ),
      ),

      home: AuthForm(),
```

this is where the problem exists like this

```
((new) AuthForm AuthForm(Void Function(String, String, String, bool, BuildContext) submitFn)   1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.

        );
      }
    }
```

**AuthForm.dart**

```
 import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {

  AuthForm(this.submitFn);

  final Void Function(String username, String email, String password,

      bool isLogin, BuildContext ctx) submitFn;

  @override

  _AuthFormState createState() => _AuthFormState();

}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var _isLogin = true;

  var _userName = '';

  var _userEmail = '';

  var _userPassword = '';

  void _trySubmit() {

    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();

    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();


    if (isValid) {

      _formKey.currentState.save();

      widget.submitFn(_userName.trim(), _userEmail.trim(), _userPassword.trim(),

          _isLogin, context);

    }
  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Center(

      child: Card(

        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),

        child: SingleChildScrollView(

          child: Padding(

            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),'

            child: Form(

              key: _formKey,

              child: Column(

                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

                children: <Widget>[

                  if (!_isLogin)

                    TextFormField(

                      key: ValueKey('username'),

                      validator: (value) {

                        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 6) {

                          return 'Name Must Be At Least 6 Characters';

                        }

                        return null;

                      },

                      decoration: InputDecoration(

                        labelText: 'Username',

                      ),

                      onSaved: (value) {

                        _userName = value;

                      },

                    ),

                  TextFormField(

                    key: ValueKey('email'),

                    validator: (value) {

                      if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {

                        return 'please enter a valid email address';

                      }

                      return null;

                    },

                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,

                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email Address'),

                    onSaved: (value) {

                      _userEmail = value;

                    },

                  ),

                  TextFormField(

                    key: ValueKey('password'),

                    validator: (value) {

                      if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 8) {

                        return 'password must be at least 8';

                      }

                      return null;

                    },

                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),

                    obscureText: true,

                    onSaved: (value) {

                      _userPassword = value;

                    },

                  ),

                  SizedBox(

                    height: 12,

                  ),

                  RaisedButton(

                    child: Text(_isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Singup'),

                    onPressed: _trySubmit,

                  ),

                  FlatButton(

                    child: Text(

                        _isLogin ? 'Create New Account' : 'I Have an Account'),

                    onPressed: () {

                      setState(() {

                        _isLogin = !_isLogin;

                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**and this is the `authform` code**

**so this is the main problem and it tells me that I have to add arguments to my `home AuthForm()`
so please fix it I Post The Code Of The Main And Also The Code Of The `AuthForm`**

Answer (score 0):

Your `AuthForm` form needs 1 parameter which called `submitFn`.
You should pass this argument to this in `home: AuthForm(),`. Consider it is not named parameter as a you defined. For more information about named parameter see [this](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters)

I suggest move `submitFn` function in `AuthForm`, instead pass from Main.
You can write your function `AuthForm`. So you didn't need to define in as final parameter.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {

  AuthForm();

  @override
  _AuthFormState createState() => _AuthFormState();

}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var _isLogin = true;

  var _userName = '';

  var _userEmail = '';

  var _userPassword = '';

  void submitFn(String username, String email, String password, bool 
  isLogin){
   // here you can call api,
   // here you can show error,
   // here you can Navigate to new page 
   // and any other things you want
 }
  void _trySubmit() {

    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();

    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();


    if (isValid) {

      _formKey.currentState.save();

      submitFn(_userName.trim(),_userEmail.trim(),_userPassword.trim(),
          _isLogin);

    }
  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Center(

      child: Card(

        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),

        child: SingleChildScrollView(

          child: Padding(

            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),'

            child: Form(

              key: _formKey,

              child: Column(

                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

                children: <Widget>[

                  if (!_isLogin)

                    TextFormField(

                      key: ValueKey('username'),

                      validator: (value) {

                        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 6) {

                          return 'Name Must Be At Least 6 Characters';

                        }

                        return null;

                      },

                      decoration: InputDecoration(

                        labelText: 'Username',

                      ),

                      onSaved: (value) {

                        _userName = value;

                      },

                    ),

                  TextFormField(

                    key: ValueKey('email'),

                    validator: (value) {

                      if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {

                        return 'please enter a valid email address';

                      }

                      return null;

                    },

                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,

                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email Address'),

                    onSaved: (value) {

                      _userEmail = value;

                    },

                  ),

                  TextFormField(

                    key: ValueKey('password'),

                    validator: (value) {

                      if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 8) {

                        return 'password must be at least 8';

                      }

                      return null;

                    },

                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),

                    obscureText: true,

                    onSaved: (value) {

                      _userPassword = value;

                    },

                  ),

                  SizedBox(

                    height: 12,

                  ),

                  RaisedButton(

                    child: Text(_isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Singup'),

                    onPressed: _trySubmit,

                  ),

                  FlatButton(

                    child: Text(

                        _isLogin ? 'Create New Account' : 'I Have an Account'),

                    onPressed: () {

                      setState(() {

                        _isLogin = !_isLogin;

                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I edit my code. I removes submit from AuthForm (and not need to send from MyApp) and i wrote it in AuthForm

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for `AuthForm` you have defined it like this,

```
AuthForm(this.submitFn);
```

Which means, that you always need to pass a compulsory param while creating a new `AuthForm`.

But in your `MyApp` you are creating it like this,

```
home: AuthForm()
```

So you are not passing the necessary param and that's why the error.

Instead create it like this,

```
home: AuthForm((String username, String email, String password, bool isLogin, BuildContext ctx) {
   // Here you have access to all the params that were sent from AuthForm
})
```

Comment: i did it but still the error exists in the parameters like he did not accept 'username' 'email' 'password' or even 'isLogin' so please i am stack do something please

Comment: ` class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'flutter chat',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        accentColor: Colors.green,
       home: Authform(),`

Comment: you have not updated your `home: AuthForm()` part ? Check my answer and give this value to home - `AuthForm((String username, String email, String password, bool isLogin, BuildContext ctx) { })` instead of just `AuthForm()`